# Combobox - initial value is right any call after that is giving an error during casting

Tags: c#, combobox

I am trying to get the guid value of a combobox.

Here be my code:

```
private void PopulateComboBox()
{

  using (var ent = new SuburbanPortalEntities())
  {
    var qry = (from x in ent.Corporations
      select x).ToList();

    comboBox_CompanyId.DataSource = qry;
    comboBox_CompanyId.DisplayMember = "CompanyCode";
    comboBox_CompanyId.ValueMember = "CorporationId";
  }
}
```

And I'm referencing it here:

```
   private void comboBox_CompanyId_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      using (var ent = new SuburbanPortalEntities())
      {
        var corpid = ((Corporation) comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue).CorporationId;
        // ^^ this is where the exception occurs
        //var corpid = (Guid) comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue;
        // ^^ tried this but the form initialization gives an exception

        if (corpid == Guid.Empty) return;

        var qry = (from x in ent.Trucks
          where x.CorporationId == corpid
                orderby x.TruckNumber
          select x).ToList();

        if (!qry.Any()) return;

        comboBox_TruckNumber.DataSource = qry;
        comboBox_TruckNumber.DisplayMember = "TruckNumber";
        comboBox_TruckNumber.ValueMember = "TruckId";

      }
```

The first time I get the corpid, during the form initialization, it works fine. When I change the value in the combobox, it gives me this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 
>   TruckTransactions.data.Corporation'.

I'm not sure I understand why the type in my combobox is changing.

Comment: Is it throwing on this clearly invalid cast, or somewhere else? `((Corporation) comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue)`. You went to great lengths to tell it to make `SelectedValue` a Guid. Then you take `SelectedValue` and cast it to `Corporation`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I added a few notes above to show where it is giving the exception

Comment: Here is the tip. if you rush and accept the answer quick, you will miss traffic to your question. If you don't accept for a day, you will have many people come and give ideas, etc.

Comment: @T.S. Thanks for the info! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you populate comboBox_CompanyId with Corporations:

```
comboBox_CompanyId.DataSource = qry;
comboBox_CompanyId.DisplayMember = "CompanyCode";
```

Here, you tell it to use the `CorporationId` property of the selected `Corporation` (a `Guid`) as the `SelectedValue`:

```
comboBox_CompanyId.ValueMember = "CorporationId";
```

Here, you take the `SelectedValue`, which you insisted must be a `Guid`, and you cast it to `Corporation` instead, with predictable results:

```
    var corpid = ((Corporation) comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue).CorporationId;
```

Now, the way you could have diagnosed this was to put in a breakpoint and hover the mouse over `comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue` in the debugger, instead of asking strangers on the internet what's going on in the code running on your own desktop. Then you would have found that `comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue` was *already* the CorporationId you want.

### tl;dr

```
var corpId = (Guid)comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue;
```

`comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedItem` is a `Corporation`.

Comment: ty for the response. I had that in there and I 'thought' I tested it but apparently not well enough. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue
```

do

```
comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedItem
```

Problem solved.

Here is what happens

```
// here
var corpid = ((Corporation) comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue).CorporationId;
// comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue is already corporation id
// because you did this --> comboBox_CompanyId.ValueMember = "CorporationId";
// so you should be able to do
var corpid = (cast type)comboBox_CompanyId.SelectedValue;
// or, do what I said above
```

On another note, first set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. Assign `DataSource` last - performance

Comment: Thanks for the help! I also changed the latter part.